# Vagrant not running Symfony 2 application

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant

For some reason I cant access my application with Vagrant?

I have setup Vagrant on Windows 8.1. Downloaded a vagrant box from puphpet.com. Run Vagrant up, everything installed correctly. Added "192.168.56.101 symfony.dev" to my windows hosts file. 
I mapped my Symfony project, which is located in this path "D:\Code\symfony", to the Vagrant /var/www/ folder. 
When I connect to Vagrant through ssh I can see the project files are mapped correctly. 
On the browser when I try to access http://symfony.dev/ or 192.168.56.101 I get the message "Unable to connect". I tried to ping the Vagrant ip(192.168.56.101) and it works correctly.

What could be the problem?

Here is my Vagrant config.yml

```
---
vagrantfile-local:
    vm:
        box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        hostname: ''
        memory: '2048'
        cpus: '1'
        chosen_provider: virtualbox
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.56.101
            forwarded_port:
                0SvjyPI6UDuD:
                    host: '7889'
                    guest: '22'
        post_up_message: ''
        provider:
            virtualbox:
                modifyvm:
                    natdnshostresolver1: on
            vmware:
                numvcpus: 1
            parallels:
                cpus: 1
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: site.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder:
            wJk9mT1cz51r:
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
                source: 'D:/Code/symfony'
                target: /var/www
                sync_type: default
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                    auto: 'false'
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: null
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: null
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        ilkrufagjrp3:
            servername: symfony.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            docroot: /var/www/web/
            port: '443'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
                - 'APP_DEBUG true'
            directories:
                jef7iojt3d1j:
                    provider: directory
                    path: /var/www/web/
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - all
                        - granted
                    custom_fragment: ''
            engine: php
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl: '1'
            ssl_cert: 'D:/Code/ssl_certificates/server.crt'
            ssl_key: 'D:/Code/ssl_certificates/server.key'
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
    mod_pagespeed: 0
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        wpxscadpw3qi:
            proxy: ''
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome
            listen_port: '80'
            location: \.php$
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            envvars:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            engine: php
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
php:
    install: '1'
    version: '56'
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
            - curl
            - mysql
            - sqlite
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
    timezone: America/Chicago
    mod_php: 0
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: '9000'
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
    timezone: null
xdebug:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: v0.17.1
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 6.3.0
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions:
        G5gzwEe1inxM:
            version: ''
nodejs:
    install: '0'
    npm_packages: {  }
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions:
        NThrCoRVZqMY:
            version: ''
mysql:
    install: '1'
    override_options: {  }
    root_password: root
    adminer: 0
    databases:
        EITE80HRHyKG:
            grant:
                - ALL
            name: symfony
            host: localhost
            user: user
            password: '123'
            sql_file: ''
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        root_password: '123'
        user_group: postgres
        encoding: UTF8
        version: '9.3'
    databases: {  }
    adminer: 0
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    override_options: {  }
    root_password: '123'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
    version: '10.0'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
mailcatcher:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default
        from_email_method: inline
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '13000'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
    binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 1.4.1
        java_install: true
solr:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 4.10.2
        port: '8984'
```

Comment: I didn't see the port forward setting, do you have separate setting in `Vagrantfile` as this line  `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 80`

Comment: @BMW The one that I've posted is the config.yml from which the Vagrantfile reads the settings. So in this case guest: 22 and host 7889

Comment: but that's not http port, with is 80. Try `http://192.168.56.101:7889` , do you see any web page?

Comment: @BMW I tried it, did not work. Also tried it with port 80, still did not work

Comment: could you please login the box (192.168.56.101) and access with "curl http://192.168.56.101:7889" or "curl http://192.168.56.101", do you get any contents? you can replace curl with wget, if you don't have curl command.

Comment: @BMW it fails to connect on both occasions

Comment: so is the Symfony service running well on the vagrant instance?

Comment: @BMW I dont know what you mean exactly, but if I run for example "php app/check.php" I get all the requirements "OK"